# Why is setPersistence not working in Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to keep users signed in regardless of the page they are on until they choose to log out. I am trying to do this by initializing the firebase config on each page to have a persistence type of browserLocalPersistence. Unfortunately, the user is not currently staying signed in after the page is changed/reloaded. Where am I going wrong? There are no errors being produced.

```js
import {
  initializeApp
} from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.7/firebase-app.js'

// Add Firebase products that you want to use
import {
  initializeAuth,
  signInWithEmailAndPassword,
  signOut,
  setPersistence,
  browserSessionPersistence,
  browserLocalPersistence,
  indexedDBLocalPersistence
} from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.7/firebase-auth.js'

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "xxx",
  authDomain: "xxx.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://xxx.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "xxx",
  storageBucket: "xxx.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "xxx",
  appId: "xxx",
  measurementId: "xxx",
  persistence: browserLocalPersistence
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = initializeAuth(app);
console.log(app, auth);

auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if (user) {
    console.log('User logged in: ', user);
    const navRight = document.getElementById('navRight');
    navRight.innerHTML = `<a id="logout" href=".">LOGOUT</a><a href="../about/">ABOUT</a>`;
    // Logout
    const logout = document.getElementById("logout");
    logout.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log('User logged out');
      signOut(auth).then();
    });
  } else {
    console.log('User not logged in');
  }
});

const loginForm = document.querySelector('#login-form');
const loginButton = document.getElementById("login-button");
var identification = "";
var password = "";

// Login
loginForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  console.log(1);
  e.preventDefault();
  var identification = loginForm['identification'].value;
  var password = loginForm['password'].value;
  var loggedIn = false;
  console.log(2);
  setPersistence(auth, browserLocalPersistence);
  setPersistence(auth, browserLocalPersistence)
    .then(() => {
      // Existing and future Auth states are now persisted in the current
      // session only. Closing the window would clear any existing state even
      // if a user forgets to sign out.
      // ...
      // New sign-in will be persisted with session persistence.
      return signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, identification, password);
    })
      .catch((error) => {
      // Handle Errors here.
      const errorCode = error.code;
      const errorMessage = error.message;
      console.log(errorCode);
      console.log(errorMessage);
    });
```

Comment: So it logs `User not logged in` whenever you refresh the page? Also the persistence is local by default so have you tried without specifying persistence explicitly

Comment: @Dharmaraj Yes, that's what it logs. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Like just run `signInWithEmailAndPassword` directly on button click and remove any persistence related thing. Also try using the modular syntax for `onAuthStateChanged` that is `onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {...})` as in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user)

Comment: @Dharmaraj sigh I deleted all of the persistence things and set up the method like above and it's still saying user not logged in on refresh/page change :(

Comment: On most browser-based environments Firebase persists the user credentials by default already. So I recommend first removing the `setPersistence(auth, browserLocalPersistence);` calls and trying with just the sign-in code. If you still have the problem with that, please show the updated (and likely much smaller) code in your question.